# Using JESS rule engine with R

Tags: r, rule-engine, expert-system, jess

I'm currently working on a weather pattern prediction system development for my final year project which is a group project.

We need to crate a rule based system for pattern prediction. We used R for data mining purposes, therefore we intend to R for rule based system development as well.

I would like to know if there any method to use JESS in R?
If not then any simple way to create a rule system in R?

Any answer with coding example is highly appreciate.

Comment: There may not be a cogent reason to "use Jess in R". - If you mine the data, you have the data. You write the rules, run the inference engine and pass it the data. No need to use the same language for both.

Comment: so then how am I supposed to pass the mined data? and where should I write rules?. Where is the inference engine if I am not using JESS?

Comment: For passing the mined data: use a file if you don't need to pass the data in real time, otherwise a socket connection from R to a Java application which uses Jess as an inference engine, with rules written in Jess.

Comment: Can you provide me some coding examples for creating a rule in JESS. I'm not familiar with it though I asked it. even a link will be a great help

Comment: There is the Jess user manual which comes with a Jess installation. Or read it online http://www.jessrules.com/docs/71/. And Google will find you more.

Answer (score 0):

One can use rJava to call java from R. You can give a shot ..